# EC2 AMI, does it mean state or just the program files and OS?

Tags: amazon-ec2, snapshot, amazon-ami

I was wondering if creating an EC2 AMI backup, which means taking a snapshot would just save the OS, along with its settings or say, if a program were running and during that I take an EC2 AMI snapshot. The next time I fireup the EC2, I would see the programming running again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running state is not kept in any kind of backup or AMI snapshot, although if you create a new AMI image based on your current running instance all the rest (config files included) will be kept.

Have a look at this awesome Alestic instructions in how to create a new AMI image based on a running instance: http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-ami-bundle